# laravel Eloquent Relationships withCount on relation

Tags: laravel

I have two tables

```
1. users (id,name, address)
1,abc,address1
2,xyz,address2

2. books (id,user_id,book,price)
1,1,book1,10
2,2,book1,10
3,1,book2,15
4,1,book3,20
```

When I run Eloquent query like this

```
User::with('books')
    ->withCount('books')
->wherein('id',[1,2])->get();
```

It give me result of count each user under books

Relationship is done properly.

> ```
> What I want is
> 1. total count of all user books
> 2. total sum of price for all user
> ```

how can I do that in Eloquent

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this

```
User::with('books')
    ->withCount([
       'books as total_book',
       'books as total_price' => function($query) {
          $query->select(DB::raw('sum(price) as total_price'))
        }
    ])
    ->wherein('id',[1,2])
    ->get();
```